# Pattern matching throwing an Exception

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below 2 XML Files.

**Title.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
<file name="LCCPMY_CH_01.xml"></file>
</entry>
```

**Contents.xml**

```
<toc-pg>1</toc-pg>
```

and the content of **LCCPMY_CH_01.xml** is as below.

```
<chapter num="A">
    <section level="sect1">
    <page num="1"/>
        <title>
            <content-style font-style="bold">Chapter 1: This is Chapter</content-style>
        </title>
        </section>
</chapter>
```

here what i'm trying to do is from Content.xml file, by using the help of Title.xml file, i'm trying to match the number(`page num of LCCPMY_CH_01.xml is equal to Contents.xml toc-pg value`). I'm using the below XSLT to do it.

```
<xsl:template match="toc-pg" mode="x">
<xsl:variable name="dot" select="."/>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:variable name="prent">
                <xsl:for-each select="document('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\MY\2014\The Law of Costs in Civil Proceedings\title.xml')/entry/file">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(document(concat('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\MY\2014\The Law of Costs in Civil Proceedings\',./@name))/chapter/section[@level='sect1']/substring-after(fn:substring-before(.,':'),' ')[//page/@num=regex-group(1)]|a[//page/@num=regex-group(1)])"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="cha">
                <xsl:value-of select="$prent"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="size">
                <xsl:value-of select="string-length($cha)"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="conct">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$size>'1'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('er:#LCCPMY_CH_',$cha,'/pg_',.)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('er:#LCCPMY_CH_0',$cha,'/pg_',.)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <a href="{$conct}">
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

but when i'm running this I'm getting the below Exception.

```
XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Error: file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/MY/2014/The%20Law%20of%20Costs%20in%20Civil%20Proceedings/09172014/XSLT/MCCL_TOC_01.xsl:235: Not a node item - item has type xs:string with value '1' -   Details: -     XPTY0020: The context item in an axis step must be a node
```

please let me know where am i going wrong and how can i fix this. I use XSLT 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: is this `<xsl:when test="$size>'1'">` line 235? If so, I believe this should be changed to `<xsl:when test="$size > 1">`

Comment: Hi @JoelM.Lamsen, thanks for the reply, the error shown is at  `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(document(concat('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\MY\2014\The Law of Costs in Civil Proceedings\',./@name))/chapter/section[@level='sect1']/substring-after(fn:substring-before(.,':'),' ')[//page/@num=.]|a[//page/@num=.])"/>`

Comment: The problem is with the predicate `[//page/@num=.]` where the context item is a string, a string does not belong to any document so using `//page` to access `page` elements in a document does not work as it is not clear which document you want. Explain which document you want to search there or define a variable outside which stores the root node of that document with e.g. `<xsl:variable name="doc" select="..."/>` and then access `[$doc//page/@num=.]` in the predicate.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, sorry for that mistake, i was just trying other alternatives. I've updated my XSLT with the original. Here in this example, i want to search in `LCCPMY_CH_01.xml` for page number, once it is done then match it with the value in `<toc-pg>` and after it matches i want to get the number i.e. the chapter number `<title>
            <content-style font-style="bold">Chapter **1**: This is Chapter</content-style>
        </title>` i want to retrieve this bold `1`

Comment: You can't do `/substring-after(fn:substring-before(.,':'),' ')[//page/@num=regex-group(1)]` as in that step you compute a string and then add a predicate doing `//page` which requires the context item to be a node while it is a string. So you need to store the document where the `page` elements are in in a variable and use a variable reference.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, this is where i'm stuck, unable to know how to do it. please help me with this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the problem is with this line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(document(concat('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\MY\2014\The Law of Costs in Civil Proceedings\',./@name))/chapter/section[@level='sect1']/substring-after(fn:substring-before(.,':'),' ')[//page/@num=regex-group(1)]|a[//page/@num=regex-group(1)])"/>
```

To show this more clearly, let's assume the `document` call has been stored in a variable `$doc-lccpmy` for now. Then, with some indentation, it looks like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="
     normalize-space(
         $doc-lccpmy/chapter/section[@level='sect1']/substring-after(substring-before(.,':'),' ')[//page/@num=regex-group(1)]
         |
         a[//page/@num=regex-group(1)]
    )"/>
```

There are a couple things wrong with this. Firstly, as pointed out by MartinHonnen in comments you are trying to apply the expression `[//page/@num=regex-group(1)]` to a string, when the context should be a node. To fix this, the first part of the expression should (probably) be this

```
$doc-lccpmy/chapter/section[@level='sect1'][page/@num=regex-group(1)]/substring-after(substring-before(.,':'),' ')
```

Also not how the `//` has been removed to make it relative to the `section` element.

The other issue is the use of the `|` which is the union operator (It is not an 'or' operator).

```
 $doc-lccpmy/... | a[//page/@num=regex-group(1)]
```

By using this in the position you are using it, you will be returning the union of two node-sets, to return a sequence of nodes, and a sequence is not allowed as an argument of the `normalize-space` function.

Unfortunately, because your XML sample does not have an `a` element, it is not clear what exactly needs to be done to fix it, but it possibly needs to look like this

```
$doc-lccpmy/chapter/section[@level='sect1'][page/@num=regex-group(1) or a/page/@num=regex-group(1)]/substring-after(substring-before(.,':'),' ')
```

Or, in its long form, try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(document(concat('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\MY\20‌​14\The Law of Costs in Civil Proceedings\',./@name))/chapter/section[@level='sect1'][page/@num=regex-group(1) or a/page/@num=regex-group(1)]/substring-after(substring-before(.,':'),' '))"/>
```

Or maybe this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(substring-before(document(concat('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\MY\20‌​14\The Law of Costs in Civil Proceedings\',./@name))/chapter/section[@level='sect1'][page/@num=regex-group(1) or a/page/@num=regex-group(1)],':'),' '))"/>
```